# Saving variable to another class before system exit

Tags: java, android, frameworks

Hi i'm working on an android game.

I'm trying to assign to get the value of a variable in another class, however I lost the value when I do system exit.

I've tried using sharedpreferences to save the score, but my gaming class is a non-activity and I cannot use context in the constructor, as I am using a framework that has pre-defined parameters.

Is there anyway to store the variable value to the other class before using system-exit to close the game?

I've also tried starting an intent to the fragment as opposed to system exit, but I always get a nullpointer Exception, in fact its more of a problem that I'm unable to successfully pass context parameters

```
Here is my constructor

public GameScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);

}




public abstract class Screen {
    protected Game game;
    Context context;
    public Screen(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }
```

Comment: can you pass in a reference to the context?

Comment: This question is more related to your framework abilities, rather then android system. As workaround, you may start a background service, which will save all required setting to shared prefs.

Comment: @VadymVL I've added some code, is it possible to add another constructor or another way to get context for a normal java class?

Comment: @Martin thanks for your reply, i'm having trouble passing reference to context, there always seem to be a null pointer exception